# How to setup the maven project to run the JMeter tests?

Tags: maven, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am trying to setup the maven project to run the JMeter tests. Please let me know the way to setup the things to run the JMeter tests using Maven.

Answer (score 1):

For me, most natural option is to use jmeter-maven-plugin:

https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin

It has good wiki with plenty of configuration examples.

Answer (score 0):

I documented it [all here](https://github.com/djangofan/launch-jmeter).  This project describes how to do it with Gradle and also with Maven.   Personally, I think the Gradle version is a little more stable but the Maven version allows for nice HTML reports.